# Scope for default parameter in Python

Tags: python, parameters, scope, parameter-passing, default-parameters

I am learning Python and came across an example that I don't quite understand. In the official tutorial, the following code is given:

```
i = 5

def f(arg=i):
    print(arg)

i = 6
f()
```

Coming from c++, it makes sense intuitively for me that this will print 5. But I'd also like to understand the technical explanation: "The default values are evaluated at the point of function definition in the defining scope." What does the "defining scope" mean here?

Comment: *"Defining scope"* means the scope in which the function is being defined, i.e. the one containing `i = 5`, where the `def` line is executed. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761

Comment: "Defining scope": in Python you can have a locally scoped function, i.e. a function within a function.  The closest you get to that in C++ is a lambda, which are newish in C++ (Python has lambdas as well).

Comment: Short answer: default values are stored as tuple in `f.func_defaults`, its value is `(5,)` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. i = 5
2. 
3. def f(arg=i):
4.     print(arg)
5. 
6. i = 6
7. f()
```

At #1, `i = 5` is evaluated and the variable and its value is added to the scope.

At line 3, the function declaration is evaluated. At this point all the default arguments are also evaluated. `i` holds the value `5`, so `arg`'s default value is `5` (and not the symbolic `i`).

After `i` changes value on line 6, `arg` is already 5 so it doesn't change.